# Sending notifications to Bluetooth devices (such as Fitbit)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, fitbit, ancs

The device in question (Fitbit Surge) currently has no public BLE API exposed, so there is no documented way of interacting with it.

It does however support displaying some mobile device notifications (only incoming calls and text messages AFAIK). My guess is that in case of iOS it uses [ANCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html).

I'm interested in making the wristband vibrate programmatically from an iOS application. I figured that *maybe* dispatching system notifications is the way to go.

I saw that for Android there is [bitTicker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.newimage.bitticker) which basically acts as a proxy so that e.g. WhatsApp notifications get passed to Fitbit as text message notifications.

I was wondering if the same is actually possible on iOS as well. I'm considering both private and public iOS API solutions (not planning to release this application to App Store). Is there a way of somehow *synthesising* incoming call / message notifications so that they are passed to Fitbit? Is there some other way of approaching this problem?

I would appreciate any insights in this matter.

Comment: Would love to know if you found a solution to this eventually :)

Comment: Me 2. Did you get access to vibrate on your fitbit ?